# the meaning of "set off" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *Jaspers even records a dream in which, during a tense conversation with some of Heidegger's critics, his friend suddenly approached and addressed him for the first time with the familiar du. **The two then set off together, alone.***

[Source](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/01/06/books/chapters/06-1st-lilla.html?pagewanted=all)

What do you think "set off" means in the context of the above sentence. I considered the different meanings of the phrasal verb "set off" but none makes much sense for me.

Comment: The source is the last two sentences of Paragraph 13 in this [extract in the NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/01/06/books/chapters/06-1st-lilla.html?pagewanted=all)

Comment: *Set off* means *depart* or *leave* as correctly stated by @tdmsoares. But his explanation of *together* is not correct. Which is why I wrote [a new question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77304/how-can-two-people-leave-together-alone-dont-together-and-alone-mean-op) about the sentence and [in my own answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/77305/27803) looked at the meanings of *alone* and *together*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to English Thesaurus, the meanings of *set off*, can be, among the many meanings, compensation or departure.
In this case *set off* means depart, leave...
Does it sound crazy?

Together, means, **(the main meaning is accompaniment, junction, union) but it can means in some cases: synchronism (according to English Thesaurus), when adverb**. In this phrase together means in context *at the same time*.
So the meaning of this phrase can be understood as:

> The two then set off (leave) together (at the same time), alone.

In this [definition,](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/together_1#together_1__7) together can mean *at the same time* in some cases

Comment: Do you by any chance mean an English **thesaurus**? And if so, which one are you referring to?

Comment: @oerkelens I just edited the answer with the right name of the dictionary. Sometimes ot happen when typing on phone... Thanks!

Comment: @oerkelens English Thesaurus from Dictdata I'm using in Android

Comment: After due consideration I have had to downvote this answer because it incorrectly states that in the sentence at hand *together* primarily means *at the same time*. Actually, it has its normal primary meaning of *in each other's company* or *with each other*.

Comment: @GoDucks The main meaning of together is something like join. But in some cases as in the context of that question means also at the same time. You can see: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/together_1#together_1__7

Comment: When two people *set off together* they naturally *set off at the same time*. But *at the same time* is not the primary meaning here. The primary meaning is *in each other's company*, as [I have shown](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/77305/27803).